# Trying to make this Carousel responsive

Tags: css, carousel

I made this CSS carousel after following a tutorial online and realized it wasn't responsive. I have tried resizing the images how ever, it doesn't effect the actual carousel, I tried adding bootstrap to see if it would help but no luck. to clarify I am trying to make the size of the carousel responsive, I have already made the images responsive. I really like the look of this carousel and would like to use it for my porfolio.  any suggestions?

```css
#wrappercarousel {
  perspective: 2500;
  -webkit-perspective: 2500;
  width: 1000px;
  margin:60px 0 40 auto;
  perspective-origin: 50% 150px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 150px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s, -webkit-perspective;
  transition: 1s, -webkit-perspective;
  -o-transition: perspective, 1s;
  transition: perspective, 1s;
  transition: perspective, 1s, -webkit-perspective;
  -o-transition: -o-perspective, 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-perspective, 1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-perspective, 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

#image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: spin 24s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 24s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 24s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 24s infinite linear;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20em;
  color: #fff;
}

#image > .i1 {
  transform: translateZ(485px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(485px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(485px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(485px);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(500px);
  -webkit-perspective: 2500px;
  perspective: 2500px;
}


#image > .i2 {
   transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(485px);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(485px);
   -o-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(485px);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(485px);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(500px);
}


#image > .i3 {
   transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(485px);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(485px);
   -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(485px);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(485px);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(500px);
}

#image > .i4 {
   transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(485px);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(485px);
   -o-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(485px);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(485px);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(500px);
}

#image > .i5 {
   transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(485px);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(485px);
   -o-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(485px);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(485px);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(500px);
}

#image > .i6 {
  transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(485px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(485px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(485px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(485px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(500px);
}

#image > .i7 {
   transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(485px);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(485px);
   -o-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(485px);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(485px);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(500px);
}

#image > .i8 {
   transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(485px);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(485px);
   -o-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(485px);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(485px);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(500px);
}

#image > .i9 {
   transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(485px);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(485px);
   -o-transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(485px);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(485px);
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(500px);
}

#image img{
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class= "animated fadeIn " id="wrappercarousel">
  <div id="image">
    <div class="image i1"><img src="/images/carousel/oliver%20people.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i2"><img src="/images/carousel/newmaui.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i3"><img src="/images/carousel/Theo1.jpg"></div> 
    <div class="image i4"><img src="/images/carousel/Sunday%20Somewhere.jpg"></div> 
    <div class="image i5"><img src="images/carousel/oliver%20people.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i6"><img src="images/carousel/newmaui.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i7"><img src="images/carousel/Theo1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i8"><img src="images/carousel/Sunday%20Somewhere.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrappercarousel {
    perspective: 2500;
    -webkit-perspective: 2500;
    max-width: 1000px;    
    width:80%;
    margin:6% 0 4% auto;
    perspective-origin: 50% 150px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 150px;
    -webkit-transition: 1s, -webkit-perspective;
    transition: 1s, -webkit-perspective;
    -o-transition: perspective, 1s;
    transition: perspective, 1s;
    transition: perspective, 1s, -webkit-perspective;
    -o-transition: -o-perspective, 1s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-perspective, 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-perspective, 1s;
  }
   #image img{
    height: 300px;
    max-width: 400px;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
```

This should work

You made a common mistake applying width in pixel
Pixel in img's

Pixel will most of the time fail to add up responsive

Comment: Thank you for taking to time to respond. How ever, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fiddle

i have edited and fix , hope this one helps you

```css
#wrappercarousel {
  perspective: 2500px;
  -webkit-perspective: 2500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  perspective-origin: 50% 150px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 150px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s, -webkit-perspective;
  transition: 1s, -webkit-perspective;
  -o-transition: perspective, 1s;
  transition: perspective, 1s;
  transition: perspective, 1s, -webkit-perspective;
  -o-transition: -o-perspective, 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-perspective, 1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-perspective, 1s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

#image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: spin 24s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 24s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 24s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 24s infinite linear;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20em;
  color: #fff;
  overflow:hidden
}

#image>.i1 {
  transform: translateZ(185px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(185px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(185px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-perspective: 2500px;
  perspective: 2500px;
}

#image>.i2 {
  transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(185px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(185px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(185px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(185px);
}

#image>.i3 {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(185px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(185px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(185px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(185px);
}

#image>.i4 {
  transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(185px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(185px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(185px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(185px);
}

#image>.i5 {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(185px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(185px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(185px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(185px);
}

#image>.i6 {
  transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(185px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(185px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(185px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(185px);
}

#image>.i7 {
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(185px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(185px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(185px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(185px);
}

#image>.i8 {
  transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(185px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(185px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(185px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(185px);
}

#image>.i9 {
  transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(185px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(185px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(185px);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(185px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg) translateZ(185px);
}

#image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated fadeIn " id="wrappercarousel">
  <div id="image">
    <div class="image i1"><img src="/images/carousel/oliver%20people.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i2"><img src="/images/carousel/newmaui.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i3"><img src="/images/carousel/Theo1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i4"><img src="/images/carousel/Sunday%20Somewhere.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i5"><img src="images/carousel/oliver%20people.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i6"><img src="images/carousel/newmaui.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i7"><img src="images/carousel/Theo1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image i8"><img src="images/carousel/Sunday%20Somewhere.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I manipulated your code a little and got it spot on! Thanks for your time and your help really appreciate it!!!